# Finding the values of x and y from given condition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^y = y^x$ and $x-y=2$, find the value of $x$ and $y$. Please give me the necessary steps too!

Comment: what is nature of $x,y?$

Answer (score 1):

Note: the only integers satisfying $x^y = y^x$ are $(a, a)$ for any integer $a \neq 0$, $(1, 0), (0, 1)$, $(2, 4)$ and $(4, 2)$.

Now which pair gives you $x - y = 2?$

Essentially, for positive *real numbers*, you can determine when $$y\ln x = x \ln y \iff \dfrac{\ln x}{\ln y} = \dfrac x y \iff \dfrac {\ln x}{x} = \dfrac {\ln y}{y}$$

Comment: I m surprised that the method is purely hit and trial. I do wonder if there is general algebraic solution for this.

Comment: It would be better if you explain the shape of $\frac {\ln x}{x}$, and then that if $y_x$ is the unique solution for a given $x$ in the domain $e < x < \infty$, then $y_x - x$ is a strictly decreasing function (requires proof), hence the condition of $x - y = 2$ implies that a unique solution exists, which we can verify is $(4, 2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $x=y+2,$

$$(y+2)^y=y^{y+2}-->(1)$$

Clearly, $y\ne0$  let $y=\frac pq$ where $q\ne0, p$ are relatively prime integers.

So, $q^2(p+2q)^{\frac pq}=p^{{\frac {p+2q}q}}$

as $(p,q)=1$ and the right hand side doesn't have any power of $q\implies q=1$

So if $y$ is rational, it is an integer,

$$\left(1+\frac2y\right)^y=y^2\text {which is an integer}$$

So, we need $y\mid 2\implies y$ can be $\pm1,\pm2$

Observe that $y=2$ satisfies  $(1)$